# AndroidX Test - ActivityScenario onView() can't find nested child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, robolectric, androidx-test

I have an activity `MyActivity` which in turn holds a fragment `MyFragment`. In `MyFragment` I show a BottomSheetDialogFragment using the `childFragmentManager` as below:

`bottomSheetFragment.show(childFragmentManager, "BottomSheetFragment")`

The below is my test case (using AndroidX test / Robolectric) running in JVM.

```
  @Test
  fun isBottomSheetShownTest() {
    val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity::class.java)

    FakeViewModle.showBottomSheet() // Posts on a LiveData to show the bottom sheet

    scenario.onActivity {
      val fragment = it.supportFragmentManager.fragments[0]
      val bottomSheet = fragment.childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("BottomSheetFragment")!!
      val view = bottomSheet.view!!
      val findViewById = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.bottomSheetTitle)
      val visibility = findViewById.visibility // View is present and Visible
    }

    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.bottomSheetTitle)).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)))
    // Throws androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching
  }
```

The above test case fails with "androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching".
But within the `scenario.onActivity {}`, I am able to see the inflated BottomSheet fragment. On debugging, I found that the BottomSheet is fully inflated as is in Resumed state.

My Questions are:

1. What does `Espresso.onView()` hold? When I checked the View hierarchy, I see the MyActivity and MyFragment but not the BottomSheet.
2. Is it not possible to get the nested child fragment using `Espresso.onView()` ?
3. How do I assert if a View is present in my BottomSheet, by using `Espresso.onView()` instead of querying the `scenario.onActivity` ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find any solution?